# How to fix Attribute Error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python

I am currently making a discord bot in python. I am relatively new and have no idea how to fix this error. It sounds like some other people have had this error before, but I'm not sure how to use their solutions in my code. So far the bot should just respond with "Hello!" when the user types "$hello" I expect this to return the message "Bot has connected to Discord!", but get this error -  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Here is my code:

```
# bot.py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')


async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN'))
```

Any solutions would be appreciated! Thanks

Edit:
Sorry about not including the full error.
Here it is.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kodyneldner/DiscordBot/bot.py", line 25, in <module>
    client.run(os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please [edit] your question to include the _full_ error traceback, not just the last line, as that contains valuable information to help with diagnosing your problem

Comment: It's hard to say without a traceback as G. Anderson mentioned, but one possibility is that you don't set the environment variable that you are using `os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few reasons for the error, as well as their solutions:

1. The error is caused by Token setting the value None, which `os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')` returns if the variable does not exist or it exists and has the value None.
   Make sure that your file is *.env* is located in the same directory as the *py* file. **Make sure that it is *.env* that is created, and *not .txt file*.**
2. This error may occurs due to a failure when loading the Token value. Try to write it like this (It will probably help you):

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv('---.env')
```